# How to open a HTTPS page (with self signed certificate) in Android hybrid app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-3

I'm working in an hybrid app with Cordova 3.1 in Android.

In my application I have to open a HTTPS page that is my development server configured with a self signed certificate.

If I open the URL direclty from a browser an exception appears but I can accept it.
If I open the URL from a native app I can open the page implementing the method onReceivedSslError of WebViewClient.

But in the hybrid app with javascript, using window.open() I'm not being able to handle the ssl exception.

I have tried to install the certificate in Android 2.3.3 exporting the certificate to a .cer file and installing it with Settings > Security > Install from storage and accepting the exception in the browser but it still fails.

Any help? Thank you.

This is the AndroidManifest.XML

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.ApiManager" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">  
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>  
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="false"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>  
<!-- Push permissions -->  
<permission android:name="com.ApiManager.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="com.ApiManager.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon"> 
    <activity android:name=".ApiManager" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTask"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> 
        </intent-filter>  
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.ApiManager.ApiManager.NOTIFICATION"/>  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </activity>  
    <!-- Preference Activity  -->  
    <activity android:name="com.worklight.common.WLPreferences" android:label="Worklight Settings"></activity>  
    <!-- Push service  -->  
    <!-- In order to use the c2dm library, an application must declare a class with the name C2DMReceiver, in its own package, extending com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBaseReceiver 
        It must also include this section in the manifest, replacing "com.google.android.apps.chrometophone" with its package name. -->  
    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService"/>  
    <service android:name=".ForegroundService"/>  
    <!-- Only google service can send data messages for the app. If permission is not set - any other app can generate it -->  
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"> 
        <!-- Receive the actual message -->  
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>  
            <category android:name="com.ApiManager"/> 
        </intent-filter>  
        <!-- Receive the registration id -->  
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>  
            <category android:name="com.ApiManager"/> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver> 
</application> 
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way I have found is to generate a CA and create certs using that CA, then you must copy the .cer in the mobile and import the .cer generated for the CA in Android "Settings > Security > Install from storage".

```
openssl genrsa -out myownca.key 1024
openssl req -x509 -new -key myownca.key -out myownca.cer -days 365
```

This is the .cer to install in the mobile.

Then generate certs using that CA to be used by the servers

```
openssl genrsa -out mycert.key 1024 
openssl req -new -out mycert.req -key mycert.key 
openssl x509 -req -in mycert.req -out mycert.cer -CAkey myownca.key -CA myownca.cer -days 365 -CAcreateserial -CAserial serial 
openssl pkcs12 -export -out mykeystore.p12 -inkey mycert.key -in mycert.cer -certfile myownca.cer
```

This .p12 is the one to be used to import the new cert in the servers.

For this last cert you must use a CN the hostname of the server machine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

is present inside the AndroidManifest.xml file inside the root of your Cordova project.  I've experienced times when this is set to false, it will not accept a self signed cert.

Comment: please add that detail to your opening post.  Try to include as much detail as possible to avoid answers that won't help you.

Comment: I have added the AndroidManifest.xml to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more a workaround, but just in case it could help someone else:

I was not able to do it in a 2.3.3 but I could with 4.1.2

Also I had to export the certificates using a keystore (p12) and install the .p12 instead of the .cer in the mobile with "Settings > Security > Install from storage". (Maybe I was not generating the .cer correctly)

Also the CN of the certificate must be the hostname that you use to open the web page.

To test the configuration try to open the same URL you are trying to open from the app using the browser, if no exception appears, it is working.